# Does this ForEach view run in O(n) time?

Tags: swift, swiftui, time-complexity

I'm working on a school project with time complexity for swiftui.

```
struct ComplexTime: View {
  let arrayOfIntegers: [Int] = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
   var body: some View {
    ForEach(arrayOfIntegers, id: \.self) { int in
        Text("\(int)")
            .padding()
    }
   }
 }
```

The question is, is this view run in O(n) where n = number of element in array?

Because of Integer is not a primitive in swiftui does this affect the run time of this view?

Does Text("(int)").padding() run in O(1) or each Text and .padding run in a different time?

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant to the time complexity.  The O() notation is not interested in how long individual operations take.  It's interested in what happens to the runtime if you double the size of the input.  Whatever overhead there is will be constant for each operation.

Comment: This is a great tip that i can understand more about O()

Comment: Hmm I don’t really understand much about big O notation, but ForEach is a view made by Apple and I don’t think they tell you what goes on inside it. If you’re working on time complexity it might be better to investigate more general algorithms

Comment: If `arrayOfIntegers` is any hardcoded length, then it's a constant which is ignored from a TC standpoint. TC deals with algorithms that have dynamic-sized input, which this doesn't appear to. The code shown here is O(1).